# When attempting to decrypt a key retrieved through getkeyasync I recieve errors. What am I missing?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault

I have an RSA key stored in the KeyVault (not a secret, a key).  Using the .net KeyVaultClient I can retrieve the key.

However, when I try to decrypt the key so it can be used inside one of our applications, I am receiving an error (I have tried several methods of decrypting the key each is highlighted below, and each generates a different error message / exception).

I have tried a several methods.  I will outline each, hopefully without disclosing any of our sensitive information.

`KeyBundle keyBundle = await keyClient.GetKeyAsync(fullUri);`

Where

(i)  `keyClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(GetAccessToken)));`
 (ii) fullUri is `"https://[mycompany].vault.azure.net/keys/[keyidentifier]"`

I receive a KeyBundle object and inside that KeyBundle object I have the JsonWebKey which contains the Modulus and Exponent both as byte arrays.

Once I have these values I have tried decrypting the key using the following methods.

1. Using the `keyClient.DecryptAsync(keyBundle.KeyIdentifier.ToString(), JsonWebEncryptionAlgorithm.RSA15, keyBundel.Key.N).GetAwaiter().GetResult();` method.

I have tried changing the algorithm in the above call and receive the same error (KeyVaultErrorException):    BadRequest,

Also, I have tried replacing keyBundle.KeyIdentifier.ToString() with keyBundle.Key.Kid (which seems to hold the same value).

2. Using the `KeyVaultClientExtensions.DecryptAsync(keyClient, keyBundle.Key.Kid, "RSAOAEP", keyBundle.Key.N);`

I also receive a KeyVaultErrorException - BadRequest.

3. Using an HttpClient PostAsync event (code below) I have tried calling the Rest APi directly and receive the following exception:

> {"error":{"code":"BadParameter","message":"The parameter is
>   incorrect.\r\n"}}

Code for the Rest Api Call:

```
keyClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(GetAccessToken));

string fullUri = $"{baseUrl}keys/{keyIdentifier}";

KeyBundle keyBundle = await keyClient.GetKeyAsync(fullUri);

JsonWebKey key = keyBundle.Key;

string decryptUri = $"{keyBundle.Key.Kid}/decrypt?api-version=7.0";

                HttpResponseMessage response = null;
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AccessToken);
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                    try
                    {
                        var uri = new Uri(decryptUri, UriKind.Absolute);
                        string encryptedText = Convert.ToBase64String(key.N); //Encoding.UTF8.GetString(key.N, 0, key.N.Length);
                        DecryptionRequestInformation requestInformation = new DecryptionRequestInformation();
                        requestInformation.alg = "RSA1_5";
                        requestInformation.value = encryptedText;

                        var stringContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestInformation), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                        response = await client.PostAsync(uri, stringContent);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                        throw ex;
                    }
                }

                string encryptionResult = string.Empty;
                if (response != null)
                {
                    encryptionResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                }
```

AccessToken is the result from the call to GetAccessToken in the KeyVaultClient callback

I would like to be able to use the decrypted key in one of our applications but am unable to decrypt it.

Could someone please explain what I am missing.  I have a feeling that the byte array that is returned from the GetKeyAsync call is not what I think it is (is the RSA Modulus value (key.N) the encrypted key ?) or that I am not encoding the bytes (key.N) correctly to pass to the DecryptAsync method.

Unfortunately, many of the examples online refer to KeyVault secrets and not to keys and I cannot find any examples that seem to work when dealing with Keyvault keys.

What am I missing her please ?

Thanks in advance

Julian

Comment: The modulus and exponent are the public part of our key. The key lives in KV.  So really depends what is your use case.  The encrypt/decrypt method are they if you want to encrypt/decrypt data using the key not decrypting it itself. Could you explain what your are trying to do a little bit more please ?

Comment: @Thomas, thanks for the reply.  We have an RSA key stored in the Azure Key Vault, as a key, not as a secret.  I want to be able to retrieve that key, decrypt it and use it as an RSA key inside another application. I'm not sure how to elaborate further.  The key was generated by putty (as far as I am aware, the key was then imported into the Azure Keyvault using the Portal.  I believe at the time the key is imported it is encypted.  I want to be able to retrieve the key, decrypt it and then use the decrypted key inside another application.  Hope this helps :)

Comment: @Thomas, so I guess really, once I have the modulus and exponent, how do I retrieve the content of the key and decrypt it back into its original RSA key value ?  I think this may be the bit I am missing :(

Comment: When you've imported the key to KV did you mark the private key has exportable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your issue description and the comments, I think you may use the Azure Key Vault in a wrong way.

You can only get the public part of the key which can be used to generate the public key.

The private key will be stored in Key Vault, and will not be able to be retrieved.

So, you can use KeyVaultClient to:

1. Sign digest with private key
2. Verify signature with public key
3. Encrypt data with public key
4. Decrypt data with private key

The Sign and Decrypt operations can only be performed with KeyVaultClient. The Verify and Encrypt operations can be performed locally, as you can generate the public key with modulus and exponent from the key's public part.

If you do want to get the private key and use it in your application, I think you have to use secret. Secret is just the thing you want: you can store it on Azure safely, and retrieve it when needed.